# Set listener on every word of sentence and add in layout dynamically

Tags: android, textview

I want to set a sentence in view, but I want to set listener on every word of sentence and the sentence will be added in view run time.
SO I add text views in horizontal linear layout but how I can if line ends then add text views on new line or suggest some other solution for my problem.

Comment: Why not add a multi-line textview?

Comment: Please elaborate more so we can understatnd what do you want exactly.

Answer (score 0):

You need [`TextView.getOffsetForPosition`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getOffsetForPosition%28float,%20float%29)